# iOS open URL in safari instead of Facebook in-app browser JS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ios, facebook

I just want to ask is there a chance to open url in safari instead of facebook in-app browser with javascript or HTML?

The problem is that I need to open it from either Facebook time line or by clicking link inside in-app browser. I have found some solutions here over stackoverflow, but none of them worked. Maybe you have any suggestions how to do that?

Because I saw that there was some changes over iOS 8, so maybe there is a new way to work around

Comment: There is not any way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately iOS Safari app doesn't have a URL scheme that you could use to open your links from different app like FB.
You can make it work for a different browser app though, like Chrome. See
http://www.labnol.org/internet/open-in-chrome-bookmarklet/21526/